# Get meta_value from GDRating

Tags: meta-query, meta-value

I am trying to get meta value from GD Rating table for each post ID with following sql:

```
$querystr = "SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->gdrts_itemmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'stars-rating_rating'";
$ratings = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);
foreach ($ratings as $rating)
{
    $rating->meta_value;
}
$ratingku = get_post_meta($post->ID, $rating, true);
```

But it failed, It return a word: "ARRAY".

How to get meta_value from another table (created by a plugin) for each post by using SQL or Query?

Comment: Is the problem $wpdb->gdrts_itemmeta? You didn't say what the failure was. I'd guess you'll need to construct the table name yourself from `$wpdb->prefix . "gdrts_itemmeta"`.

Comment: How exactly did it fail? Did you try to dump the `$ratings` - `var_dump( $ratings );` - and is it empty? Are there any errors? And is that `$rating->meta_value;` a typo? Also, shouldn't the `$ratingku` be *inside* the `foreach` loop?

Comment: It give empty result. I think it failed cause the result from querystr is not associated witf post ID.

Comment: Actually, have you tried `echo $rating->meta_value;` ? And you could also just use `wpdb::get_col()` - `$ratings = $wpdb->get_col( $querystr );` - this way, you'd get an array of meta values and not an array of meta object. (I.e. You could simply `echo $rating;` in the `foreach`)

Comment: The issue have been solved.